# Me aparece un segundo scroll en mi documento html, com ocultarlo

Tags: html, css, div

Como ocultar un scroll en html con css, al trabajar en pagina con contenedores, en el cuerpo de el documento me aparece un segundo scroll a que se debe esto ? o como puedo ocultarlo o eliminarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, muestra el código que tengas hasta el momento, aún así te puedo decir que puedes optar por ocultarlo usando el pseudo elemento **::scrollbar**, ej: `body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`

Comment: Por favor, agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento para poder reproducir el error.

Comment: Al elemento que este mostrando el scrollbar agregale en estilo (ya sea asignandolo por CSS o directamente al tag con `style`) `overflow:none;`

Comment: Asi es oculte el overflow o como comentas Roberto poniento el overflow en none, gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: @GerardoBautista usando overflow none lo que haces es eliminar el scroll por completo, de modo que no podrás hacer el elemento para que se pueda hacer scroll en el.